# Accessing join table attributes to show content on views, Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have these two models called `Users` and `Departments` which have a many to many relationship through a join table called `departments_users`. `departments_users` has `user_id` and `department_id columns`.

Now I want to list all users in the department view, that belong to this department. How would I got to accessing the info thats on `departments_users` table to filter this info, to show only users that belong to this department.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call:

```
@department = Department.find(params[:id])
@department.users
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many - gives a run down of methods available on many to many associations.

Example use case in a view:

```
<ul>
  <% @department.users.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user.name %></li>
    <li><%= user.some_other_attribute %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work. But I do see this lists, the raw data from the database, how can i filter to show only some attributes. Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: Thanks for the quick help man! Really solved my problem and helped me understand better these join tables!